# Test Linux server internet speed from command line up to 1gbit/s

Tags: linux, performance, internet, test

Does anyone know a way I can test a Linux servers connection speed from ssh? I could use wget but I can't find a file that can be downloaded fast enough. I'm trying to verify that the server can do a gigabit per second.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try using [iperf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/) for bandwidth measurements

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the [aria2c](http://aria2.sourceforce.net) downloader. It's like wget, but it supports more methods of downloading, including splitting a file up and downloading bits of it from multiple sources.
So, you could find a bunch of mirrors for some popular linux distro and have aria2 download from a bunch of them all at once. If you aren't maxing the line, just try adding more mirrors. Crude, but if you can't find a better method it might come in useful.

Answer (score -1):

This will create 1Gigabit file named out.bin. Change the bs parameter value for a greater file.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=out.bin bs=1000000000 count=1
```

Comment: this is not the answer to the question.